# From inside a method, manipulate the return value of another method C++

Tags: c++, class, methods, return

I have a class with multiple methods defined. There is one method which simply returns a value from a member variable. There is another method which I would like to 'update' the returned value from the previous method, from inside this method.

Example: (assume declarations for X have already been made in a .hpp file)

```
A::A() { 
    X = 800; //constructor initialising x & y
    Y = 1;
}
A::funcA() { 
    return Y;
}
A::funcB() { 
    if (x > y) {
        //make funcA now return 2 ...
    }
```

I can set Y to be the value I want perfectly, but how do I recall funcA to 'update' the value returned with the new value of Y I have set? When I try to call: funcA() == 2; It doesn't seem to update properly.

Comment: `Y = 2;` would cause `funcA` to return 2 from now on. I don't understand what you mean by "recall". Do you expect to be able to somehow go back in time and modify the value that the function returned some time in the past? That would contradict the laws of physics as we understand them today.

Comment: What is the return type for funcA? There does not seem to be one.

Comment: In funcB(), assign Y=2, if X>Y. If you want to re-invoke the function, manually invoke funcA() after every funcB. Maybe you can also use pointers to member functions...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to update the value of Y since that is beng returned.

```
A::A() { 
    X = 800; //constructor initialising x & y
    Y = 1;
}
A::funcA() { 
    return Y;
}
A::funcB() { 
    if (x > y) {
        Y = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example lacks a few things like return values and what your return value would be if x

Just decide in `funcA()` what to return:

```
int A::funcA(){
    if (x > y) {
        return Y; // or return 2 or whatever, just an example

    return X;
}
```

Or, have a special 'return value'

```
class A
{
  private:
    int X,Y,retA;

  public:        

    A()
    { 
      X = 800; //constructor initialising x & y
      Y = 1;
      retA=Y;
    }

    int funcA() { 
      return retA;
    }

    funcB() { 
      if (x > y) {
        retA = 2;
      }
    }
}
```

You might even go for a pointer, if you want to switch between the two variables. This prevents you from copying the value but does not allow you to return a different value than one of the stored ones.:

```
class A
{
  private:
    int X,Y;
    int* retA;

  public:        

    A()
    { 
      X = 800; //constructor initialising x & y
      Y = 1;
      retA=&Y;
    }

    int funcA() { 
      return *retA;
    }

    funcB() { 
      if (x > y) {
        retA = &X;  
        //do NOT use retA = 2 here, that would be invalid
        // *retA = 2 would be possible, but change either X or Y
      }
      else {
        retA = &Y;
      }
    }
}
```